# Getting an Error : app not found, when i click on the homescreen shortcut in android App

Tags: java, android

I have created android app shortcut on home screen using code from main activity

Shortcut got created successfully and i am able to launch the application.

Functionality is also working fine but when I click on shortcut then getting an error that app not found.

Please review my code and guide me how can I solve this problem.
Here is my main activity code:-

```
Context context = MainActivity.this;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    boolean isAppInstalled = false;
```

Here is my onCreate code

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        isAppInstalled= sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isAppInstalled", false);
        if(isAppInstalled==false){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            Intent intent2 = new Intent();
            intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, intent1);
            intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,"My Application");
            intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            intent2.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent2);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("isAppInstalled",true);
            editor.commit();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No anyone help me in this.
well i solved myself thank for all and here is my problem

I created splash activity for my app that why it will use in my code 
mean change MainActivity with SplashActivity

Here is correct Code

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        isAppInstalled= sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isAppInstalled", false);
        if(isAppInstalled==false){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SplashActivity.class);
            intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            Intent intent2 = new Intent();
            intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, intent1);
            intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,"My Application");
            intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            intent2.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent2);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("isAppInstalled",true);
            editor.commit();

        }
```